# Is it possible to access another apps database if you have the device key?

Tags: android

I am trying to access another apps database, I know it is located in

```
 "/data/data/jp.co.xxx.xxx.framework.database/databases/SETTING".
```

I have the device key and have signed my apk with the device key but I am still unable to `open the database.`

Is `this possible` with just the `device key,` I do not have the shared user id?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think, android allow you to access database of another app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible with just the device key, I do not have the shared user id?

Not normally. Your process will still run as a different user ID. Signing with the device key will help in terms of getting `signature`-level Android permissions but has no impact on your ability to get to read another app's files.

*If* the other app is also signed by the same key and *if* you can synchronize `sharedUserId` values, then you could access the data. Or, if you run as root, you could access the data. Or, the best answer is for the authors of the other app to work with you to expose an API that you can consume, rather than your hacking into their database directly.